# Is it possible to create an asset bundle without Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

We need to create asset bundles automatically on our server, but having Unity installed on the server and running it via command line would fit badly in our server design. So we're wondering if there's any other way to create asset bundles. A .Net library you could run from regular .Net would be optimal but we're interested in any solution you may have.

Comment: I don't think that you can do this without the editor, for now. Even if you make some script/program that automates that, you will still need Unity installed afaik. In the future Cloud Build will support asset bundle building, but it doesn't look to be arriving anytime soon http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/asset-bundle-support.268916/

Comment: I know that is possible to run Unity without graphics interface and perform builds/run custom scripts. Probably you can start assetbundling from command line too. But you still will need Unity installed on server